# Night Color and Redshift not working in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, night-light

I have tried many different things, but neither Night Color in KDE or Redshift works in Kubuntu 20.04.

This is a fresh install in with a Nvidia RTX 2070 graphics card and B550 motherboard. I'm not sure what else could I try

Comment: Which window manager are you using? The built in Night Color feature requires Kwin to work.